# Kendo UI and Toast Image Editor conflict in Angular 7 project

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, conflict

How can I use Kendo UI and Toast Image Editor?
I used ngx-tui-image-editor npm module.
The image editor is working well but when I try to navigate to a new page which contains Kendo UI component, page get fault and takes so much memory more than 1GB.
If you have any experience with this, please help me.

```html
<div>
    <tui-image-editor 
        id="imageEditor" 
        [options]="imageEditorOptions"
    >
    </tui-image-editor>
</div>
```

```ts
this.imageEditorOptions = {
  includeUI: {
    menu: ['crop', 'filter'],
    initMenu: 'crop',
    loadImage: {
      path: itemval.Client_Result_Photo_FilePath,
      name: itemval.Client_Result_Photo_FileName
    },
    theme: {
      'menu.normalIcon.path': icond
    },
    uiSize: {
      height: "614px",
      width: "680px",
    }
  },
};
```

```html
<kendo-upload 
    [saveUrl]="uploadSaveUrl" 
    [removeUrl]="uploadRemoveUrl" 
    [(ngModel)]="myFiles"
    (error)="displayError($event)" 
    (success)=displaySuccess($event);
>
</kendo-upload>
```

Comment: The Vue version had memory issues too, maybe there's something similar in the Angular version: https://github.com/nhn/toast-ui.vue-image-editor/pull/19

Comment: Thanks for your help.